# Tensorflow codes exceptionally exit when using thread in a loop

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to describe my problem as much as possible for receiving valuable answers. For this, I am posting the pseudocode below and then pointing out my further question:

```
for _ in range(100):
   tf.reset_default_graph()
   read data from the queue
   build the graph
   with tf.Session() as sess:
       coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
       threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess, coord)
       try:
            for i in range(total_steps):
                if coord.should_stop():
                  do my work...
       except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('done')
       finally:
            coord.request_stop()
            coord.join(threads)
```

In summary, I put my code in the loop, and in each loop. the graph is reset, and then use thread to read data.

I have used the command "nohup python myscript.py >./log.txt &", while no exceptional or error messages in the log.txt.

Now, I am thinking whether the threads causing this exceptional exit? But I am not sure.

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "causing this exceptional exit"? Is there some sort of error?

Comment: Because the threads are used in my for-loop context, I am afraid these threads caused my codes exceptional exit due to the incorrect usage of threads.  Yesterday, I asked this problem from the IT, they help me to determine that the system killed my process. But further reasons are unknown.